# Python convention for raising exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I am having difficulty finding a good data source for how exceptions should be handled and raised. Should the helper function or class method handle raising an issue or is it normal convention for the caller to handle the logic for catching an exception?

Do we do this in both places and just follow the stacktrace all the way?

Option A:

```
def change_permissions(file):
    os.chmod(file, 0o755)

try:
    change_permissions('/Users/user/Documents/file.txt')
except Exception:
    print('do something with this')
```

Option B:

```
def change_permissions(file):
    try:
        os.chmod(file, 0o755)
    except EnvironmentError:
        print('do something with this')

change_permissions('/Users/user/Documents/file.txt')
```

Comment: If you are looking to supress the exception, its always better to handle like Option B, else choose Option A type

Comment: except Exception is very vague. Option B is better because it specifies the error.

Comment: In general, you should preserve failure as values (e.g. raised exceptions) as long as possible, although that doesn’t mean you can’t catch and rethrow more detailed exceptions like `except EnvironmentError as e: raise ChangePermissionException("Failed to change permissions because (details)") from e`. (But handling the more specific error is good advice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't catch exception as e

The issue with catching Exception is related to type inheritance (hence, the interlude) because we won’t just be catching all custom exceptions in your application but a whole heap of Python inbuilt exceptions as well, including some you might not want to be throwing away.
You need to g with specifically since so option B will be the good one

## Other best practises

There are some best practises to handle exceptions in python
And it's all about you.

- Never use exceptions for flow-control
- Do not expose implementation details with exceptions
- Document the exceptions thrown by your code
- Understanding where do we need Assertions and Exceptions.

Read the following articles to understand these things.

https://medium.com/better-programming/a-comprehensive-guide-to-handling-exceptions-in-python-7175f0ce81f7

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/21/robust-exception-handling/

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/professional-error-handling-with-python--cms-25950

https://medium.com/better-programming/handling-errors-in-python-9f1b32952423